# The array remains empty even if I send items to it and they appear in it VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm facing a very strange problem that I can't figure out.
So I want to retrieve some data from an api

```
getPaymentsLinkItems() {
            let items = [];
            this.paymentLinks.forEach(async (link) => {
                let object = {};
                let response = await this.stripe.get(`/payment_links/${link.id}/line_items`);
                items.push({[response.data.data[0].price.product]: link.url});
                object = {};
            });

            console.log(items);
        }
```

Even if I send those data in the array as you can see, they appear in it but the length is 0 and I can't access anything

```
[]
0: {prod_MI6m3mRfVAG6b: 'https://buy.stripe.com/'}
1: {prod_MI6IMPKoUoo1I: 'https://buy.stripe.com/'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
async created() {
        this.stripe = this.$http.create({
            baseURL:  process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_URL,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_TOKEN}`
            }
        });
        await this.getStripeProducts();
        await this.getPaymentsLinks();
        this.getPaymentsLinkItems();
    },
```

Comment: `async` callback to `forEach` rarely if ever does what you think ... use a `for...of` loop instead

Comment: Your console log will be executed before the data comes back

Answer (score 0):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to have await calls run in parallel

```js
async getPaymentsLinkItems() {
  let items = [];
  await Promise.all(this.paymentLinks.map(async (link) => {
    let object = {};
    let response = await this.stripe.get(`/payment_links/${link.id}/line_items`);
    items.push({[response.data.data[0].price.product]: link.url});
    object = {};
  }
  console.log(items);
}
```

or use `for...of` loop to have await calls run sequentially

```js
async getPaymentsLinkItems() {
  let items = [];
  for(const link of this.paymentLinks) {
    let object = {};
    let response = await this.stripe.get(`/payment_links/${link.id}/line_items`);
    items.push({[response.data.data[0].price.product]: link.url});
    object = {};
  }
  console.log(items);
}
```